# wxPython: How to bind the button?

Tags: binding, wxpython

I just started with wxPython and have problems with the binding.

Usually the examples I find to bind a button event are done with`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnWhatEverFunction, button)`. I have a frame with a panel inside and a button and what ever I tried, the outcome is always a flashing frame that appears in a split second and that's it. Since the code isn't that much I attach it here and hope one of you can show me the way out of my little problem.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx

class CPFSFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(CPFSFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
                                    style = wx.BORDER | wx.CAPTION | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX,
                                    size=(350, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        pNumberLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Project number: ')
        pNumberText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(175, -1))
        pNumberText.SetInsertionPoint(0)

        pNameLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Project name: ')
        pNameText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(175, -1))
        pNameText.SetInsertionPoint(0)

        pButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Create')
        pButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCreate)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)
        sizer.AddMany([pNumberLabel, pNumberText, pNameLabel, pNameText, pButton])
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        statusBar = self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnCreate(self, evt):
        self.Close(True)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    CPFSFrame(None, title='Create New Project Folder Structure')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the "self.Show()" method in the **init** section of the code. At first I thought OnCreate() was running and if it was, then it would just close the frame immediately so you wouldn't see anything. I would call it OnClose instead. Here's a working example:

```py
import wx

class CPFSFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(CPFSFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
                                    style = wx.BORDER | wx.CAPTION | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX,
                                    size=(350, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        pNumberLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Project number: ')
        pNumberText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(175, -1))
        pNumberText.SetInsertionPoint(0)

        pNameLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Project name: ')
        pNameText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, '', size=(175, -1))
        pNameText.SetInsertionPoint(0)

        pButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Create')
        pButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)
        sizer.AddMany([pNumberLabel, pNumberText, pNameLabel, pNameText, pButton])
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        statusBar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.Show()

    def OnClose(self, evt):
        self.Close(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    CPFSFrame(None, title='Create New Project Folder Structure')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike,

after doing the same to the self.Centre() the frame even appeared at the right position. :D

I called the function OnCreate because it creates the whole directory structure for a new project. The self.Close() was just a dummy to see if it works.

Cheers Thomas