# Difference between self.Bind, self.Widget.Bind and self.EVT_EVTNAME.Bind

Tags: wxpython

The example in [wxpython](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html) uses self.Bind. But this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746549/wxpython-how-to-bind-the-button) uses self.Widget.Bind variant. The wx.EVT_EVTNAME also has the method Bind. What are the advantage and disadvantage between the three event binding methods?

Answer (score 0):

The [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind) explains the difference between `self.Bind` and `self.widget.Bind`. The 3rd method that you mention is extremely old and not recommended. I believe it comes from wxWidgets land.